# Compiling Caffe: undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to compile Caffe from the official GitHub sources + using a couple of layer cpp files added by a user. When compiling I get the following error:

```
f@f-VirtualBox:~/caffe/mts4/caffe-master$ sudo make all
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Print'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_CallObject'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyList_SetItem'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyCallable_Check'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyImport_Import'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyFloat_AsDouble'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyTuple_SetItem'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyList_New'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyTuple_New'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:560: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/caffe.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] Error 1
f@f-VirtualBox:~/caffe/mts4/caffe-master$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation error means that at least some cpp files added or altered by the user use Python. To remediate the issue, you should uncomment `WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1` in the [`Makefile.config`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile.config.example) before compiling.